# Как отправлять решение на Codeforces?

Tags: c++

Не могу понять как отправить решение в Codeforces!
Вот к примеру задача http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/616/B.
Решил её. Отправляю файл на прохождение теста, а мне пишут уведомление, что программа падает на первом тесте, хотя у меня этот тест она проходит.

### Может не в том формате отправляю?

### Кто подскажет?

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime> 

using namespace std;

int STREETS = 0;
int AVENUE = 0;

vector< vector<int> > TOWN;

void read_from_file( string file_name )
{
    ifstream ifn;
    ifn.open( file_name );
    string temp_str = "";
    stringstream ss;
    getline(ifn, temp_str);
    ss << temp_str;
    ss >> STREETS >> AVENUE;

    TOWN.resize( STREETS );

    //refresh variables 1
    temp_str = "";
    ss.clear();
    int ind = 0;

    while (!ifn.eof())
    {
        getline( ifn, temp_str ); 
        ss << temp_str;
        int number = 0;
        while ( !ss.eof() )
        {
            ss >> number;
            TOWN[ ind ].push_back( number );
        }
        //refresh variables 2
        ind++;
        ss.clear();
        temp_str = "";
    }

    ifn.close();
}

void print_TOWN()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < STREETS; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < AVENUE; j++ )
            cout << TOWN[ i ][ j ] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int find_min_in_row(int street)
{
    int min = INT_MAX;
    for ( int i = 0; i < TOWN[ street ].size(); i++)
        if ( TOWN[ street ][ i ] < min )
            min = TOWN[ street ][ i ];
    return min;
}

int find_optimum()
{
    int max_among_min = INT_MIN;
    int t_min;
    vector< int > min_s;

    for ( int i = 0; i < STREETS; i++ )
    {
        t_min = find_min_in_row(i);
        min_s.push_back(t_min);
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < min_s.size(); i++ )
        if ( min_s[ i ] > max_among_min )
            max_among_min = min_s[ i ];

    return max_among_min;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale( 0, "" );
    read_from_file( "Town.txt" );
    cout << STREETS << " " << AVENUE << endl;
    print_TOWN();
    cout << "\n" << "\n" << "\n" << "\n";
    cout << "ќптимальное решение                          :" << find_optimum() << endl;
    cout << "¬рем¤ работы                                 :" << clock() / 1000.0 << endl;
    cout << "\n" << "\n" << "\n" << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а где у вас "правильно"? Вы на текстовки посмотрите - они во-первых корявые, а во вторых - там что сказано отправлять? А что вы отправляете? И откуда вы считываете данные? Кто сказал что считывать надо из файла "Town.txt"? Ввод и вывод должен полностью соответствовать заданию, любое отклонение наказывается провалом

Comment: А что, собственно, не правильно @bopoh? Алгоритм есть?-есть. Доказать, что он инвариантен, докажите сами, т.к алгоритм слишком тривиален! А что не так с текстовками? Ну считывает из файла информацию в том виде как мне нужно и хорошо. 
Мне не понятно как записать код в `main`e , что бы соответствовал условию задачи.То что я считываю из файла, это не правильно, я это понял.

Comment: а то, что выводит совсем не в том виде, в каком надо (надо одно число, а у вас целая поэма на выводе) вас не смущает? Если у вас есть проблема с определенной программой - эту программу и показывайте. Если вы отправляете именно эту программу (что в задаче) - исправьте для начала то, что я указал (т.е. ввод и вывод).

Comment: *"что не так с текстовками?"* -- цитирую CodeForces: "ввод: стандартный ввод". Ни о каких файлах речи не идёт. Это уже достаточная причина для программы падать на CodeForces.

Comment: @D-side, ну вообще-то, говоря про текстовки, я имел ввиду, например, это: `cout << "ќптимальное решение` - такое они точно видеть у себя не хотели

Comment: @BOPOH "текстовка" у меня ассоциируется исключительно с "текстовым файлом", но это тоже проблема, да.

Answer (score 4):

Чтение из файла и вывод на консоль - это странное сочетание.

Большинство олимпиадных задач используют либо чтение с консоли и вывод на консоль, либо чтение из файла и вывод в файл. Гибридных вариантов что-то не припомню.

Кроме того, в условиях задачи указано, как осуществляется ввод и вывод.

> ```
> cout << "\n" << "\n" << "\n" << "\n";
> cout << "ќптимальное решение                          :" << find_optimum() << endl;
> cout << "¬рем¤ работы                                 :" << clock() / 1000.0 << endl;
> cout << "\n" << "\n" << "\n" << "\n";
> ```

Это тоже, скорее всего, является нарушением формата и должно быть удалено. Как правило, для отладочной информации разрешён вывод в stderr, однако гарантировать не могу.